# Need older version for safe-client-gateway

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

We have been using safe-global’s docker images for gnosis safe deployment for our production. And recently it seems the version we have been using was deprecated from docker hub as it’s bit old.
This has caused the production to be down for some time as newer images are not compatible and it seems we will have to do a new setup.
Meanwhile we want are production to be live while we work on getting the new setup ready for our chain.

Can anyone please provide access to this particular image which is not available on docker hub:

**gnosispm/safe-client-gateway:v3.15.2**

or

**safeglobal/safe-client-gateway:v3.15.2**

This would be really live safer if anyone could get this image.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the repository for that here: https://github.com/5afe/safe-client-gateway. You can checkout the old tag and run `docker build` on the required tag:

```
git clone https://github.com/5afe/safe-client-gateway
cd safe-client-gateway
git checkout rust-image-3.15.2 v3.15.2
docker build .
```

Something to note from the README of the repository:

> This project is no longer being maintained. A new version which supports the same API can be found on https://github.com/safe-global/safe-client-gateway-nest. For the teams running an instance of this service, we strongly advise using the new version as it will include new features and any security related updates.